# ${\{n\sqrt{2}\}>\frac{1}{2n\sqrt{2}}}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For $x\in \mathbb{R}$, we define $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.

> Prove that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$, $\displaystyle{\{n\sqrt{2}\}>\frac{1}{2n\sqrt{2}}}$.

I really don't see how to start. The fact that $\sqrt{2}\notin \mathbb{Q}$ is surely important but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h402624p2243245, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1751999p11424196 – found quickly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7B%5C%7Bn%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%5C%7D%3E%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2n%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D%7D%24)

Comment: Also proved as part of this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3016798/42969

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If  $p=\lfloor n\sqrt{2}\rfloor $, we have:

$\{n\sqrt{2}\}= n\sqrt{2}-p=\dfrac{2n^2-p^2}{n\sqrt{2}+p}\geqslant \dfrac{1}{n\sqrt{2}+p} >\dfrac{1}{2n\sqrt{2}} $

Comment: Next question, is it true that $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} = \text{inf}_{n\in {\mathbb N}^*} n\{n\sqrt{2}\}$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis: Yes: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3016737/42969

Comment: @Gribouillis: Yes. Hint: the equation  $2n^2-p^2=1$ has an infinite number of solutions in $\mathbb N^2$.